# What kind of drills do the schools have on Galaxy Class Starships and other facilities with civilian children?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

It's well established in canon that the Enterprise-D has schools for civilian children on board as they are shown in episodes such as "The Offspring," and a recurring character is even a teacher in the school aboard Deep Space 9.

In 21st century Earth schools we have drills for potential hazards that might befall the class such as fire, tornado, and now active shooter drills.

On a starship, what sort of drills might be common? Fire is still an issue but what about some of the more bizarre things that appear to be fairly routine on starships performing deep space exploration?

**Is there any kind of standardized series of drills taught to students who might encounter emergency situations?**

Things like:

How to recognize a time loop?

What to do if your teacher devolves into an earlier evolutionary state?

The senior staff is now children and Ferengi have taken over the ship?

That sort of thing.

Comment: We see them practicing an evacuation drill in several of the books, plus we're told that they have designated shelters, which presumably they would have to have learned

Comment: Lower Decks - Despite kurtzman and it's parody status - is the first time in-universe people are ultra-aware of just how wonderful and dangerous it is out there.  TNG kids seem like they'd just run straight to Klingons for hugs.

Comment: "things that appear to be fairly routine...  time loop... Ferengi have taken over the ship" Citation needed! These things might be routine for the Enterprise, but probably not for all Starfleet vessels.

Comment: Time loop: "cause and effect" Idk if it's common, but I cited it so give me my 2 seconds of recognition. For the Ferengi/ ship takeovers: Star trek 5, Conundrum, acquisitions (they could've captured it but just stole things), star trek 2. Yeah, they didn't have good security on those ships, did they? So it was a bit routine on other ships you could say.